# How to not have space at the right end when using using maxwidth in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to have a conversation message screen. The problem which I am facing is that if there is a word that does not fit one single line and text has to go to the next line there is a lot of space left at the right end. How to remove this redundant space at the right end?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_16dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:id="@+id/rightText"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_blue_80"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:maxWidth="300dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
        android:text="dhdjhdkjdk jdkdk nkdk dknnjfnjnfjnfmkdmmkdmk"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/delivered"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
        android:text="delivered"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rightText"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_80"/>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think you should use `marginLeft` or `marginRight` instead of setting maxWidth. It is because different devices have different pixel size.

Comment: But i want the textview to grow with the text inside i.e. if the text is small the box size should also be small but also to restrict the size to a certain value, if i use margin left I dont think I can achieve this

Comment: It looks like the XML you posted is for the blue boxes that don't look like they have the extra space at the end. Where is the XML that you use for the light grey boxes which do have the extra space at the end?

Comment: The image I posted is of the expected screen